# Swap from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, jquery-selectors

The code included is to make a second data selector to have a start date in a second data selector  30 day's ahead of the date chosen in the first data selector.

```
fbuilderjQuery(document).on('change', '#fieldname1_1_date', function() { 
  var d_from = new Date(fbuilderjQuery(this).val()), 
    to_item = fbuilderjQuery.fbuilder.forms['_1'].getItem('fieldname2_1'); 

  d_from.setDate(d_from.getDate() + 30); 
  to_item.minDate = (d_from.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d_from.getDate() + '/' + d_from.getFullYear(); 
  fbuilderjQuery('#fieldname2_1_date').datepicker('destroy'); 
  to_item.setDefaultDate(); 
});
```

This code works perfectly in an `mm/dd/yyyy` situation. The problem is I need it in a `dd/mm/yyyy` situation. I recon the writing happens in this line

```
to_item.minDate = (d_from.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + d_from.getDate() + '/' + d_from.getFullYear();
```

I switched some things around but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to understand the code but I guess I'm missing something obvious there. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Simply switching the string values should be enough *however* if that string value is parsed to a Date object then it *must* be in either MDY or YMD format as JS only parses those.

Comment: Hey there

Thanks for the comment. 

I tried [code]to_item.minDate = d_from.getDate()  + '/' + (d_from.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + d_from.getFullYear(); [/code]

But that didn't seem to work.

I setted the first date picker on dd/mm/yyyy and the second one aswell after changing that code. If i use the original code and leave both selectors on mm/dd/yyyy it does work.

Comment: Been tinkering around myself and i found if i just input a date manual :to_item.minDate = '4/3/2018'; it works setting minDate to the date I typed in there. So somehow the script isn't 'printing' the selected date.